# How to generate sequential number for distinct select in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My sql statement is

```
SELECT distinct(CATEGORY) as CategoryName
FROM APPLICATION
where applicationId = ?
```

This works fine but now what I wanted is with the categoryname I need sequentially generated number as well. For e.g if the distinct category count is 10 then each category name should have a sequential number 1 to 10. It will be good if the generated sequential number is ordered by category.

[image: entered a pic here]

Comment: Are you executing this query directly against Oracle, or from somewhere else, e.g. Java?

Comment: I am trying in Oracle if it works needs to add in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT CategoryName, rownum as seqnum
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY as CategoryName
      FROM APPLICATION 
      WHERE applicationId = ? 
     ) a;
```

If you really want to avoid the subquery, you could use `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY as CategoryName, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CATEGORY) as seqnum
FROM APPLICATION 
WHERE applicationId = ?
```

Or, you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CATEGORY as CategoryName, rownum as seqnum
FROM APPLICATION
WHERE applicationId = ? 
GROUP BY CATEGORY;
```

Either `rownum` or `ROW_NUMBER()` could be used in this case.

Comment: Group by query is not working for me but others are working fine.

Comment: Second query order by categoryName and seqnum gives better result.

Answer (score 0):

In the order of sql operations, row_number() comes before and therefore will produce distinct values before they are removed by the DISTINCT keyword, which will not be exactly a set of consecutive numbers.

So, Use DENSE_RANK()

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  CATEGORY AS CategoryName, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CategoryName) row_number
FROM APPLICATION 
WHERE applicationId=? 
ORDER BY CategoryName, row_number
```